# I can use as a "join" on "and" this in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

This is my query in MySQL

```
select * 
from une_uninegocio_mstr, ban_bancos_mstr, cue_cuentas_mstr, cued_cuentas_det 
left join tra_traspasos_mstr  on tra_cue_orig_id = cued_id and tra_fecha = cued_fecha 
where cue_cuentas_mstr.cue_id = cued_cuentas_det.cued_id
and cue_cuentas_mstr.cue_uninegocio_id = une_uninegocio_mstr.une_id
and ban_bancos_mstr.ban_id = cue_cuentas_mstr.cue_banco_id
and une_uninegocio_mstr.une_id = "1"
and cued_fecha = curdate();
```

How does codeigniter could do?

Comment: Codeigniter has models and you can build the relationships inside of them. Why are you writing raw SQL?

Comment: Don't mix implicit and explicit join syntax. Basically, never use a comma in a FROM clause.

Comment: As you would do ?
with codeigniter methods does not result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `AND` in joins.

In codeigniter its like this,

```
$this->db->join('tra_traspasos_mstr', 'tra_cue_orig_id = cued_id and tra_fecha = cued_fecha');
```

But i would suggest you to use, `tablename.columnname` in joins.